# Python Kivy real time chart

Tags: python, kivy

I am learning to use Kivy. My objective is to create an app to display a sound wave chart of a running sound.

Unfortunately, I cannot get the chart to update in real-time. I get "NameError: name 'graph' is not defined", and I don't really know how to fix it.

Code below:

```
from math import sin
from kivy.garden.graph import Graph, MeshLinePlot
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock


class MyApp(App):
    plot = MeshLinePlot(color=[1, 0, 0, 1])

    graph = Graph(xlabel='X', ylabel='Y', x_ticks_minor=5,
        x_ticks_major=25, y_ticks_major=1,
        y_grid_label=False, x_grid_label=False, padding=5,
        x_grid=False, y_grid=False, xmin=-0, xmax=100, ymin=-1, ymax=1,)

    def build(self):

        box = BoxLayout()
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_points, 1/60.)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_xaxis, 1/60.)
        box.add_widget(graph)
        return box

    def update_xaxis(self,*args):
        global graph
        graph.xmin = 0
        graph.xmax = 100

    def update_points(self, *args):
        #self.plot.points = [(i,i)]

        self.plot.points = [(x, sin(x / 10.)) for x in range(0, 101)]





MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your references to `plot` and `graph` (except where they are created) should all be `self.plot` and `self.graph`. Also, you don't want the `global graph` line in your `update_xaxis()` method. After you make that correction, you next question should be a separate post.